# "auto merge vertices" distance to small

Tags: units

I make small models in millimetre. The problem is that the vertices are close together and the auto merge vertices does not work proper.
How can I make auto merge work proper?

I know scaling up my model would work, but I like to work in millimetres.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tweak the merge distance threshold in the *Options* dropdown in the top right of the 3D viewport or in the tool settings in the properties editor.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you like to work in millimeters, go to the *Scene Properties* and set *Unit Scale* to 0.001 and the unit for *Length* to *Millimeters*. This way you can work in a larger scale so that the tools work better, but have everything in millimeters.

[image: scale units]